# How to set id for dynamically created nav-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am using bootstrap3.

I am creating nav-tabs dynamically using json format.

Now, I want the id of nav-tabs to increment.

When i use increment option like below its showing only on active tab. When i click on another tab the id is not incrementing..

Here is the code for increment

```
 $('#save').attr('save-id', function (i) {
 return 'Save_button' + (i + 1);
});
```

Comment: please provide fiddle for this..

Comment: you can try with a global variable increment that variable and assign id to tab when you initialize them..